# Does "Tschüssie" sound a little ...weiblich?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request, sociolinguistics

Actually I don't know where did I learn the word *Tschüßie*, but I suspect that is a word that is not so frequently used by men[*]. Is it true?

---

*And I don't know if there is a term for that phenomenon. And it's only a guess that there exist words used predominantly by women or men: bad words for example.

Comment: That is purely a matter of personal perception. First one I ever heard say Tschüssi is a 6 ft. 2 broadshouldered womanizing team handball player, so...

Comment: I love our bavarian "Servus". It works for everyone, on hello and goodbye, for men and women, and just about every possible occassion.

Comment: @AntonRoth [...and is latin for slave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servus)

Comment: I always thought of it as a very familiar expression exchanged by friends, both men and women.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

"Tschüssie" is definitely gendered, as far as I can tell - I've never heard a (straight) man use it without a heavy dose of irony.

It's different, however, with the more convoluted (and by now a bit old-fashioned) "Tschüssikowski" [*not* sure about the spelling] - this tends to be used more frequently by men, in my observation at least.

You might also be interested in this article on wikipedia: [language and gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_and_gender)

EDIT: Please note that this answer is a *descriptive* observation. As a general rule, stereotypes of any kind should not be perpetuated - they do exist, however, and non-natives should be aware of them.

Comment: Ob es für die Straße ist, darüber kann man streiten - keine der beiden Versionen ist jedefalls Standard :) 
Vermutlich wird es Dir mit einem einfachen "Tschüss" besser gehen.

Comment: Tschüssikowski is totally out, the hype was for a while but 20 years ago. I would remove it from the answer.

Comment: @falkb: Lol, I'm totally dating myself, or rather the people I interact with, I guess - but I still hear it occasionally...

Comment: "Tschüssi", in my perception, is also sometimes used by males in an obviously exaggerated gay context, like in comedy tv. So it, in some ears, has some flavour in this direction...

Comment: I really don't think it is a geod idea t strengthen gender stereotypes.
I have heard "Tschüssie" from men and women alike, and i am not aware of any rules that gay men have to use different words...

Comment: @Burki: Valid comment, but while I agree that stereotypes shouldn't be reinforced, just ignoring them doesn't really help... especially if the question specifically asks about gender stereotypes. And of course there aren't any rules how anybody *has* to express themselves - but I think it's fair to tell a non-native that certain expressions will create a certain impression.

Comment: It is, to the best of my knowledge, not gendered in any way. It does sound somewhat cutesie, but I've seen both men and women (straight, as far as I know - I don't go around asking people for their sexual orientation) use it non-ironically. It may be perceived differently depending on which german-speaking part of the world you are at the moment, but the same is true of nearly everything else in german as well.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there are words or phrases preferred by men or women. And they are used with different gradations, and in certain situations.

`Tschüssi` is much more preferred by women but also common for men and noone would stumble about that when a man uses it. You use it to say `Bye` to good friends.

Typical woman stuff is also: der/die/das `ist süß / niedlich` (engl. `cute`) while a man would use `schön` (engl. `beaut`), or written `LG (as Liebe Grüße)` while a man rather uses cooler stuff.

You can say that phenomenon is `Verniedlichung` vs. `Lässigkeit`.

Comment: +1 for finally mentioning the Deminutiv aspect.