# Tschüs: Aussprache Tschü-üs

Tags: pronunciation, regional, valediction

Der Abschiedsgruß *Tschüs* (oder auch *Tschüss*) hat einen ganzen [Wikipediaartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsch%C3%BCs) mit allerlei Varianten, zum Beispiel *tschüssing*, *tschö*, *tüüs*, *tschüssi* und *tschüssikowski*. Nicht aufgelistet ist aber *Tschü-üs*, wo das ü auf zwei Silben gezogen wird.

Ich wurde nun von einem amerikanischen Freund gefragt, was der Unterschied sei zwischen *Tschüs* und *Tschü-üs*. Er meinte das zweisilbige *Tschü-üs* sei ihm vorallem bei Frauen und im Umgang mit Kindern aufgefallen. 
Ich (als Frau) sage auch *Tschü-üs*, nicht *Tschüss*, bis gestern habe ich das aber noch nie hinterfragt.

**Nun meine Fragen an euch:** 
Hat die Verwendung von *Tschü-üs* statt *Tschüs* oder *Tschüss* eine Konnotation („weiblich“, „kindlich“) oder ist es eine neutrale Variante? Und, kommt *Tschü-üs* regional irgendwo besonders häufig vor?

Comment: ich weiß nicht wieso, aber irgendwie musste ich bei tschü-üs auch an frauen denken xD

Comment: Die lang gezogene Version empfinde ich als ausnehmend warm und herzlich, beinhaltet den [sehnsüchtigen] Wunsch des Wiedersehens [in besonderem Maße], würde ich, wenn ich auf jemanden sauer bin, niemals verwenden.

Comment: Ist es nicht eher ein steigender (˧˥ /tʃy᷄ːs/ _tschǘß_) oder erst steigender, dann fallender Tonverlauf (˧˥˦ /tʃy᷈ːs/ _tschǘǜß_) als echte Zweisilbigkeit (/tʃy.ʔys/ _tschühüß_)?

Comment: @Crissov, ich glaube,  "das zweite ü" ist ein wenig tiefer.  Ganz sicher bin ich mir aber nicht.

Comment: Bei Tschüssikowski musste ich lachen hahaha

Comment: Gibt es tatsächlich Leute, die *Tschüss* immer so aussprechen? Winke-winke von Carsten, der jetzt in die Heia geht.

Comment: Nebenfrage: Was ist mit Tschühüss? Jedenfalls brauchen wir die Möglichkeit Audioschnipsel einzubauen. ;) Btw.: Kann man hier wirklich "Konnotation" sagen? Passt m.E. nicht.

Comment: Ich kann diese Frage (leider) nur vom österreichischen Standpunkt aus beleuchten: Don't say "Tschüs" in Austria! Sogar die vielen deutschen Staatsbürger, die in Österreich leben (jedenfalls die ich kenne), haben sich das "Tschüs" abgewöhnt. In Österreich üblich sind: "Servus", "Baba" und (aber eher am Land) "Grias di/enk/eich", jedoch nur wenn man sich duzt. Ist man per Sie ist "auf Wiederschaun" die beste Wahl. Weiterführende Infos: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/5076/1487 Passt auch zum Thema: Der Austropop-Hit "Deutsches Mädel" von DÖF (1983): https://youtu.be/g6rZDOztZ1s?t=22m11s

Comment: "Tschü-üs" wird vor allen Dingen verwendet, wenn man ruft, sprich der andere weiter entfernt ist. So wie man dann auch "Tscha-au" rufen würden.

Comment: @Crissov, ich habe zwei Arten von Tschü-üs. Erstens echte Zweisilbigkeit, zweitens mit fallendem Tonverlauf. Erstens verwende ich normal,  zweiterea wenn ich betonen will,  dass wir uns jetzt wirklich verabschieden und getrennte Wege gehen.

Comment: @user unknown. mit stimmlosen "h"?

Comment: "Tschüss mit Ü!" (gehört in Österreich) :-)

Comment: Übrigens [Tschüssie](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/does-tsch%C3%BCssie-sound-a-little-weiblich).

Comment: @splattne: Hören kann man in Österreich viel. Es sind ja viele Deutsche bei uns. Unter den 8,6 Mio Einwohnern Österreichs befinden sich mehr als 200.000 Deutsche damit sind sie auf Platz 1 der Liste der bevölkerungsstärksten Ausländergruppen in Österreich, mit großem Abstand vor Türken und Serben. Aber nicht nur unter den Immigranten, auch unter den Touristen nehmen Deutschen den 1. Platz ein. Teilt man die 50 Mio Nächtigungen deutscher Touristen in Ö. gleichmäßig auf 365 Tage auf, sind jeden Tag rund 135.000 deutsche Touristen in Österreich.

Comment: @splattne: Falls ein Österreicher doch mal "Tschüß" sagt, dann tatsächlich am häufigsten in der Phrase "Tschüss mit Ü". Das ist aber sehr oft gar nicht als Gruß gemeint, sondern als Aufforderung an den Angesprochen, sich möglichst rasch zu entfernen. Alternativ kann man diese Phrase manchmal von Leuten hören, die krampfhaft (aber erfolglos) versuchen witzig zu wirken. Beide Verwendungsformen werfen kein gutes Licht auf den, der die Phrase verwendet, weshalb man darauf eher verzichten sollte. Anders wird "Tschüss" von Österreichern - wie schon geschildert - so gut wie gar nicht verwendet.

Comment: Um die Regionalfrage zu beantworten: Breiß! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde sagen, dass Tschü-üs eine Nähe oder Intimität ausdrückt. Eigentlich ist es einfach nur ein langgezogener Vokal. So würde ich mich von guten Freunden oder geliebten Menschen verabschieden.
Genauso kann man z.B. das u in G**u**ten Tag langziehen (*Guuuten Taag*).

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Zusammenhang zwischen "Guuuuuten Tag" (was in meinen Ohren seltsam klingt) und "Tschü-üs".

Comment: @Iris Regional wird ‚Guten Tag!“ oder „Guten Appetit!“ zu /gu:dn/ verkürzt, mit ähnlicher Längung wie bei ‚*Tschühß‘, aber ohne den Tonverlauf oder Hiatus von ‚*Tschü(h)üß‘. Der damit ausgedrückte Nähecharakter, der meist weiblich assoziiert wird, ist aber m.E. ähnlich.

Comment: Es entsteht durch die unterschiedlichen Tonhöhen und nicht durch das Langziehen.

Answer (score 2):

**Zur Schreibung**

Gemeint ist ein zweisilbiges 'Tschü-üs'. In vielen solchen Fällen benutzt man als orthographischen Silbentrenner ein 'h', das nicht gesprochen wird, sondern lediglich die Silbengrenze markiert, so z.B. bei 'gehen', 'höher', 'Näherin' usw.

Einfaches 'Tschüs' wird kurz gesprochen, demnach könnte man sich darauf einigen, ob 'tschüss' mit '-s' (wie 'bis', 'Bus' ...) oder '-ss' (wie 'Fass', 'er schloss' ...) zu schreiben wäre. Der Duden lässt bei 'tschüs' beide Schreibungen zu. Bei Interjektionen und lautmalenden Wörtern gibt es oft keine eindeutige Regelung, und wohl auch keine einheitliche Ausspracheweise. Ich würde dessen ungeachtet die zweisilbige tschüss-Variante nicht als 'langvokalig' verstehen und sie deswegen auch nicht mit '-ß' schreiben, denn die Längung der Silbe beruht auf der nicht rein sprachlichen Zugabe, dass das zweisilbige 'tschühüs' quasi gesungen wird. Um das wirklich deutlich zu machen, würde ich am liebsten ein musikalisches Notensymbol hinzufügen: [image]
Das Intervall der beiden 'Töne' kenne ich als eine mehr oder weniger verwaschene (kleine) Terz wie bei 'Kuckuck', dann sollte das Notenzeichen rechts-links-spiegelbildlich geschrieben werden.

**Meine Assoziationen**

Ich empfinde dieses gesungene 'tschühüs' als familiärer und privater, zum Teil auch als 'unernster' bzw. fröhlicher als so ein kurz hingesagtes 'tschüss'. Für mich ist es gefühlsbetonter, weicher, geht leicht in Richtung 'Empfindsamkeit' und 'Innerlichkeit' und ist damit automatisch 'uncooler'. Da es dazu keine überprüfbaren Korpora gibt, ist das eine rein subjektive Sichtweise.

Answer (score 1):

Das Phänomen dürfte nicht auf *tschüss* beschränkt sein: Auch *ciao* kann kurz oder langgezogen ausgesprochen werden, und gleiches gilt für alle anderen Abschiedsworte, die auf der letzten Silbe betont werden *(ade, adieu …).* Bei *servus* oder bei *pfüa di* geht das natürlich nicht.

Die Erweiterung wäre dann, nicht mehr nur *tschüß* mit betont überlangem *ü* zu sagen, sondern auf *tschühüß,* mit deutlich hörbarem *h* auszuweichen. Ich glaube aber, dass hier lediglich eine Verstärkung vorliegt.

Interessant ist viel eher noch die Frage, wie der Vokal klingt. Ist es ein kurzes *ü* wie in *füttern* oder ein langes *ü* wie in *Füße?* In letzterem Fall sollte man das Ergebnis des Langziehens auf jeden Fall mit *ß* schreiben, also *tschüß.*

Ich glaube nicht, dass das Langziehen *a priori* auf eine bestimmte Personengruppe schließen lässt, weder beim Sprechenden noch beim Hörenden. Allerdings fände ich es seltsam, wenn es mir in einem Kontext, in dem ich *Sie* erwarte, begegnen würde. Das eröffnet einem umgekehrt die Möglichkeit, einen langgezogenen Abschiedsgruß all jenen zukommen zu lassen, die man duzt, ob es jetzt nur das Kollegen-du ist, oder die nächsten Familienmitglieder.

---

Was die Regionalfrage betrifft: In Bayern wird *tschüss* an sich schon nicht verwendet, dementsprechend auch keine verlängerte Version. Dafür hört man gerne mal ein langgestrecktes *ciao~*.

Comment: Es ist immer ungünstig, Begriffe zu benutzen, die man nicht versteht. Unabhängig davon, ob es in der Frage wirklich um *Konnotation* geht, ergibt *a priori auf eine bestimmte Personengruppe schließen* in diesem Zusammenhang absolut keinen Sinn.

Answer (score 1):

*Tschüss* oder *tschau* klingen in ihrer Einsilbigkeit unfreundlich und desinteressiert. Die Längung zu *tschü-üss* und *tscha-au* erlaubt eine emotionalere Intonation und damit mehr Freundlichkeit und Anteilnahme.

Ob die Verwendung geschlechterspezifisch ist, kann ich nicht beurteilen, es würde aber dazu passen, dass Frauen (der Forschungslage nach) emotionaler kommunizieren als Männer.

Comment: unfreundlich nicht, im gegenteil; Desinteressiert schon eher, durchaus, immerhin teilt man ggf. mit, dass man kein dem Abschied entgegenstehendes Interesse bekunden möchte. Die Unfreundliche Variante gibt es aber unabhängig davon wohl auch, im Sinne *verzieh dich*.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe anlässlich der Frage mal überlegt, was ich selbst sage, und das Ergebnis ist, dass ich situationsabhängig beide Aussprachen benutze.
Bei einer direkten Verabschiedung mit Augenkontakt benutze ich das einsilbige *Tschüs*.
Bei einer Verabschiedung aus größerer Entfernung (der Fortgehende - das kann der andere oder ich selbst sein - ist in Eile, weil er seinen Bus kriegen muss), zwischen dem im Türrahmen stehenden und den noch am Tisch sitzenden, benutze ich automatisch das de facto zweisilbige *Tschü-üs*.

Answer (score -1):

**Antwort:**

Der eigentliche Unterschied ist die Tonhöhe des Vokals. Da Frauen durchschnittlich eine höhere Stimme haben, kann der höhere Ton mit Ihnen assoziiert (*Frau*, langes *au*, *Mann*, kurzes *ann* -- Zufall?). Ganz einfach. Ich würde aber nicht behaupten wollen, der Effekt sei bei diesem Wort besonders gut messbar.

Darüber hinaus wäre wohl ein verstärkender Effekt durch kulturelle Einflüsse zu verzeichnen, wie schon hier in den Kommentaren deutlich wird. So habe ich mal gehört, ich glaube im Quatsch Comedy Club, "Tschüssiekofski" wäre "tuntig".

---

**Zur Phonologie**

**Einsatz:**
Zur Veranschaulichung kann man mal die Techno-Beatbox immitieren: 'Un-tz 'un-tzz 'Un-tz 'un-tzz. Nicht zufällig wird diese in der Regel mit U wiedergegeben, das eben relativ tief klingt und vorallem einen Kehlkopfverschlusslaut im Ansatz zeigt, der Druck aufbaut um die tiefen Schwingungen zu betonen und sich gegebenenfalls auch unter dem Rauschen in *tschüss* verstecken mag, bei *tschühüs* aber eher fehlt (im Selbstversuch). Letzteres dürfte unter dem Schlagwort *Kopfstimme* beschrieben werden.

**Vokalismus:**
Tonhöhe spielt auch sonst eine wichtige Rolle, nicht nur fallend oder steigend bei Aussagen bzw. Fragen, sondern etwa auch ca. eine kleine Terz in Rufnamen: "Wilfried! Hier her!". So oder so ähnlich verhällt es sich dann auch mit "Tschü-üs" als Rufwort, was in mehreren Varianten eindeutig zu unterscheidenden ist, die sich schriftsprachlich nicht ohne weiteres wiedergeben lassen, denen entsprechende Konotation zugeschrieben werden kann (die sich zwar beschreiben ließe). Das reicht natürlich vom einfachen "Tsch-üs" bis zum Glissando über eine ganze Oktave.

Dieses einfache Symbol "tschüs" erweckt wohl bei jedem Leser leicht unterschiedliche Assoziationen. Wie das Neutral zu beschreiben sein soll und in welcher Hinsicht überhaupt, kann ich nicht sagen. Die gesamte Bandbreite der einfachen Abschiedsformeln von "komm zurück" bis "verzieh dich" kann prinzipiel aufmoduliert werden. Der Sprachökonomie wegen hat das seine Grenzen, aber wo darin semantisch bzw. tonal der neutrale Mittelpunkt liegen soll, hängt wohl vom Kontext ab. Klar zu unterscheiden sind sicherlich Frage und Antwort im Schema: "ich geh jetzt" - "ja gut" ("ich auch"); aber sicherlich nicht immer, denn im Zweifelsfall genügt ein nahezu unbetonter Vokal (also wie in *Matj*e*s*, nicht En. *Chess*).

**Coda:**
Man könnte wohl sagen, *tschüss* mit abfälligem Ton sei besonders kurz, das betrifft aber auch den Schlusskonsonant, daher macht es nun gar keinen Sinn, diesen grafisch zu verlängern. Man kann natürlich auch *tschüs-ss* sagen, dann klingt man eben wie eine falsche Schlange. Das *s* kann trotz Auslautverhärtung ansatzweise stimmhaft im Übergang von Vokal zu Konsonant sein. Ist der Übergang länger als der Rest, wird man trotzdem der Gewohnheit nach eher ein stimmloses S hören, da mehr Anteile im hochfrequenten Bereich anklingen, ungeachtet der Dauer.

---

Ich würde gern mehr zur Phonetik schreiben, doch mir fehlt das Vorwissen. Eine Unterscheidung zwischen einer oder zwei Silben in *Tschüüs* ist nicht immer möglich. Abschließend kann man wohl sagen, was in Englischer Grammatik als langer Vokal gilt, ist eigentlich ein Diphtong. Und so dürfte es sich hier in den meisten fällen wohl auch verhalten, wenn nicht ein Hiatus oder gar Konsonant /h/ dazwischen eingefügt wird.

Der Unterschied zwischen langen und kurzen Vokalen ist linguistisch zweifelhaft. Jedenfalls ist die aus dem Deutschunterricht bekannten Form nicht verallgemeinerbar, der vor allem die sowieso nicht immer logische Schreibweise bespricht. Im Sanskrit spricht man dagegen von *leichten* und *schweren* Silben; Über Japanisch oder Arabisch sagt man, dort gebe es wirklich lange Vokale, aber davon verstehe ich nichts. Ob bei uns allein die Tonhöhe oder noch Charakteristika wie *offen/geschlossen* mitwirken, und die Länge nur eine Folge davon ist, tut wohl nicht wirklich was zur Sache.

Comment: Hast Du was getrunken? Was ist das denn für ein Kuddelmuddel und Geschwafel? "Letzteres dürfte unter dem Schlagwort Kopfstimme beschrieben werden." - Von wem denn? Im Rauschen des Tschüss verbirgt sich ein U wie in Utnz, utnzz, untz? Groß-Kleinfehler verbesser ich mal nicht und fehlende Wörter werde ich hier auch nicht nachtragen.

Comment: @userUnknown ähh, ja, ich hatte ein Helles dazu verspeist! Was ein Kehlkopf-Verschlusslaut ist, weißt du aber. Zu [Kopffstimme](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopfstimme) siehe die Enzyklopedie deiner Wahl.

Comment: "Die Mittelstimme ist bei der Frau das Hauptregister der mittleren Tonlage." Damit lag ich zwar knapp daneben, bin aber als einziger auf die Lage eingegangen. Dafür darf man sich schonmal ein Gesöff genehmigen. Weiter heißt es, die Bruststimme sei beim Mann das Mittelmaß. Tiefer liegt noch der Kehlkopfgesang, der mit *tschüs* jetzt nicht soviel zu tun hat. "Unter dem Rauschen" soll heißen, dass kein knackender Hiatus entsteht, kein "tsch-'üs", sondern schon im T, ganz normal. Das versuche ich mir wieder selbst zusammenzureimen, daher ist es vielleict nicht ganz richtig

Comment: Mir ist nicht klar, wie sinnvoll die Frage nach der *Konnotation* wirklich ist. Diese Antwort finde ich dagegen zumindest interessant. An der Rechtschreibung könnte man noch ein bisschen feilen, das ist schon wahr.

Comment: @Olafant wär Rechtschreibfehler findet, darf sie behalten. Ich habe zumindest "tschüs" absichtlich so geschrieben.

Comment: @vectory Das ist nett. Mir reichen aber meine eigenen. An *tschüs* gibt es m.E. nichts auszusetzen. Hast du denn alles andere auch absichtlich so geschrieben? ;)