# How should I spell the valediction ‘tschüss’?

Tags: spelling, valediction

I have seen variants of the word *tschüss*.

> 1. tschüss
> 2. tschüß
> 3. tschüs

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tschues) lists *tschüs* and *tschüss* as correct spellings, one with a long *ü* and one with an short *ü*. 
Is there one variant that is preferred?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44699/discussion-on-question-by-eva-how-should-i-spell-the-valediction-tschuss). Also note that there is [a Meta discussion on the on-topicness of asking for preferred ways of spelling](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1173/2594). Finally, please do not use comments for answering the question.

Answer (score 9):

The oldest variant is the one spelt *tschüs*. It derives from the Latin valediction *ad Deum* over the French *à Dieu*, later *adieu*. In colloquial German, this was turned into *tschö* in some parts (because of the similarity of the French *eu* phoneme and German *ö*) but modified into *tschüs* in others. Going by its spelling, *tschüs* probably has a long *ü* sound (which *tschö* definitely has) but one cannot be fully certain.

Over time, this form merged onwards towards *tschüß*, making sure that the final *s* had to be pronounced as /s/.<sup>[1]</sup> According to the old spelling rules (in place from 1901 to 1996), this could have been pronounced both with a long and with a short *ü* — the orthographic rules allowed for both.

In 1996, as a part of the reformed orthography, the distinction of whether to write *ss* or *ß* was no longer based on morpheme boundaries but only on vowel length: short vowels were to be followed by *ss* and long vowels by *ß*. Many Germans pronounce *tschüss* with a short vowel, hence the suggestion of writing it with a double-*s*. However, some people will still pronounce it with a long *ü*, requiring the spelling to be *tschüß*. If you wish, you can see two different pronunciations of the same word, giving rise to two different spellings.

Technically, the *tschüs*-form would still be valid for those pronouncing it with a long vowel. However, I would recommend you use either *tschüß*<sup>[2]</sup> or *tschüss* which I perceive to be the more common spellings nowadays.

---

**Notes:**
[1]: Of course, there is terminal devoicing in German, meaning that even *tschüs* can only be pronounced with a terminal /s/. But that could have lost the sound /s/ in cases of derivatisation.

[2]: If you are in Switzerland, the preferred orthography is always without *ß*, so *tschüss* in any case. However, the word *tschüss* is perceived as a northern word (at least in Bavaria) so I assume that using it in Switzerland will automatically put a large stamp reading *German* (the nationality) on your forehead. Probably similar with Austria and the *Piefke* stamp.

Comment: Related (but in German only): http://german.stackexchange.com/q/29271/16660

Comment: @Iris Na dann will ich doch die Frage gleich mal mit einer zweiten Meinung ausstatten ;)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that it should not have come to prominence along with *tschau*, Ita. *ciao*, which has a quite different etymology on wiktionary. Anyone, and I mean absolutely anyone alive today who learns both words will lexicalize them as variants of one lexeme. Anything you said about the derivation is kind of interesting, but absolutely irrelevant because *tschüss* and *tschühüß* are phonetic spellings and as such two simply different words, that are as different to each other as to *tschau*. Tschüss!